# How to dynamically update textview inside recycler view with handler thread

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-handler

I'm trying to update my `TextView` with `Handler` thread from `RecyclerView` here the thread is getting executed successfully but my `TextView` is not getting updated every second.

Here's my code:

```
val timerHandler = Handler()
var sec: Int = 0
var min: Int = 0
var hour: Int = 0
updater = Runnable {
    sec.inc()
    if (sec > 60) {
        sec = 0
        min.inc()
    }
    if (min > 60) {
        min = 0
        hour.inc()
    }

    if(min >= 10 && hour >= 10 && sec >= 10) {
        holder.txthrs.setText(hour.toString() + ":" + min.toString() + ":" + sec.toString())
    } else {
        holder.txthrs.setText("0" + hour.toString() + ":" + "0" + min.toString() + ":" + "0" + sec.toString())
    }
    settime(hour.toString() + ":" + min.toString() + ":" + sec.toString(), position.inc())
    timerHandler.postDelayed(updater, 1000)
}
timerHandler.post(updater)
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating the textview on UI thread. Add this inside `Runnable {}`:

```
override fun run() {
    holder.txthrs.setText(hour.toString() + ":" + min.toString() + ":" + sec.toString())
}
```

Comment: That's was silly of me just forgot that method thanks it's working now

Answer (score 0):

You would not run a timer on a `RecyclerView.Holder` at all.

Suppose you have an adapter with a fixed possition holding the timer value. Then you only need to update that value within the adapter and notify the listener about the change.

```
fun setTime(time: String) {
    this.time = time
    notifyItemChanged(timeItemIndex, time)
}

adapter.setTime(timeString)
```

I addition you'd have to manage a possibility to stop the timer as well.